# Understanding how the pointer referencing works

Tags: c++, com, pointers, guid

I am currently reading "Developer's Workshop to COM and ATL 3.0".  Chapter 3 introduces GUIDs, referencing and comparisons.  Pointers are painful.  I could use some help in deciphering the `REFGUID #define` (see below) and how `memcmp` in `IsEqualGUID` works against the pointers.

Given:

```
  typedef struct_GUID{ unsigned long Data1;  
    unsigned short Data2;  
    unsigned short Data3;  
    unsigned char Data4[8]; } GUID;
```

How do I interpret this `#define`?:

```
 #define REFGUID const GUID * const
```

How is the `&rguid1` addressing the incoming variable?

```
   BOOL IsEqualGUID(REFGUID rguid1, REFGUID rguid2)  
    {  
      return !memcmp(&rguid1, &rguid2, sizeof(GUID));  
    }
```

Comment: You should learn about pointers by themselves not while trying to understand a complicated library like ATL.

Comment: Thanks for the comment jmucchiello.  If you see the response from Preet below it appears the code in the book is incorrect.  This is what threw me.  While I'm not an expert on pointers I don't believe myself to be a beginner either.  The book's incorrect code is what threw me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The REFGUID is constant ptr to a constant guid (ie neither can change).

Shoud the code not be?

```
 BOOL IsEqualGUID(REFGUID rguid1, REFGUID rguid2)  
 {        
   return !memcmp(rguid1, rguid2, sizeof(GUID));      
 }
```

as memcmp takes:

```
int memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);
```

The memcmp should be passed the pointers (rguidx) not the address of the pointer.

if looks like the code was originally written with REGUID defined as a const GUID or const GUID reference (C++) perhaps

Comment: I suspect you're right.  I bet Joe mixed the C declaration for REFGUID and the C++ definition for IsEqualGUID.

Comment: Great feedback Preet.  I copied the code straight from the book.  Which appears to be wrong given the feedback I see in the answers.  If the book illustrated the memcmp to appear as you state above then I wouldn't have been thrown by the syntax necessitating the question on SO.  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 4):

REFGUID is defined differently in C++ and C context. If you look at its definition, it is:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define REFGUID const GUID &
#else
#define REFGUID const GUID * 
#endif
```

IsEqualGUID() function also has different implementations.

I do not like this idea. I guess that the person invented this just to make it "C++ right" because the C++ inventor believes that reference is better than pointer.

Comment: actually this perfectly addresses the original poster's question. up-voting.

the memcmp Joe was asking about only makes sense with the C++ REFGUID definition.

Answer (score 3):

The define REFGUID is a pointer to a `GUID` for which the following is true

1. The pointer cannot be re-assigned to a different `GUID`
2. The contents of the GUID when accessed through the pointer are considered const

Answer (score 1):

```
#define REFGUID const GUID * const
```

is equal to (not C++ code, abstract!)

```
const GUID * const  ==  REFGUID
```

and it is equal to

```
GUID const  * const  ==  REFGUID
```

so it is const pointer (can't change poiter) to a const GUID object (can't change the value).